Where can I find a MATIC-USDC liquidity pair contract for Uniswap on Polygon's Mumbai testnet?
I'm working on a DeFi application and need to swap between MATIC and USDC via Uniswap V2. To do this, I need to find (or make) a liquidity pair contract to do this, but I am unsure how to do this.

Note that the Mumbai Testnet has been deprecated in favor of the new Amoy Testnet.
This happened because Goerli was sunset at the beginning of this year and Mumbai settles to Goerli.
You can find info on Amoy here: https://polygon.technology/blog/introducing-the-amoy-testnet-for-polygon-pos

In a semi-related question, someone mentioned this address, which is apparently just such a contract:
0xe11A86849d99F524cAC3E7A0Ec1241828e332C62
